# How can I mock an NSZone?

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

OCMock doesn't currently support loose matching of primitive arguments. Yet I have a property that I need to set on an `OCMockObject`, and this property is declared with the `copy` attribute. It therefore implements `- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone`. `NSZone` is defined as `typedef struct _NSZone NSZone`, and as it's a struct, it's a primitive type. Hence I get the error

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'id' to parameter of type 'NSZone *' (aka 'struct _NSZone *')
```

on this line:

```
[[mockObject expect] copyWithZone:[OCMArg any]];
```

Is the best way to resolve this declaring the property with the `retain` attribute rather than `copy`? The benefit of using `copy` is that the object has no possibility of getting modified by another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NSZone** is a pointer. While OCMock doesn't provide "loose" matching for primitive types it does have [OCMArg anyPointer] to match, well, any pointer.

That said, if you just call **expect**, and not also **andReturn:**, then the mocked method will just return *nil*, which may not be what you want. My guess is the following is a better solution in your case:

```
[[[mock expect] andReturn:mock] copyWithZone:[OCMArg anyPointer]];
```

This obviously doesn't create a copy of the mock, it simply ensures that the mock itself is returned from the invocation of **copyWithZone:**.

Answer (score 3):

Just call -copy instead? It'll call -copyWithZone:, and the zone argument is completely useless.